# Could not find or load main class on linux but on windows it works

Tags: java, linux, deployment, build, executable-jar

I have a java project which I wrote on windows using netbeans. After I deploy the project and execute the deployed jar on windows it works without problems.

So I copied the project on ubuntu in order to see if I can open the jar in ubuntu. After I double clicked on the jar file nothing happened so I decided to execute the jar using terminal and the error I got is: `Error: Could not find or load main class Main.Main`

I executed the jar using this command prompt: `java -jar "BFFT_One4All.jar"`

Here is how My Folder looks like:

[image: Main class]

[image: Project structure]

[image: jar file]

The only way I can execute the jar file on linux is by installing netbeans on linux and run the programm via netbeans. If I just want to open the jar file it won't work.

Can it be that the manifest is wrong? Although I can't even find the manifest file in my project, but it still works in windows

Comment: Perhaps if you rename it to main.jar, as far as I know Linux is case sensitive and Windows isn't.

Comment: @Cambesa I tried it already... I don't know how it is possible that it works on Windows but not on Linux. It should have the same classpaths etc